# CSV uploading issue

Tags: python, csv, geocode

I am uploading csv files to https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/ for batch geocoding. After some python code to parse and separate files. I have to manually save each CSV file with excel as a csv again or I get an error "Malformed input file or file not of type .CSV, .TXT, .DAT, .XLS, or .XLSX

The data should be in separate columns in a CSV or Excel file. Use a comma separator for text or DAT files" . I opened with a text editor and notice one difference the comma at the end of each line. Is this an encoding issue?
example
Working

```
5028156,2700 W BETHANY HOME RD,Phoenix,AZ,
```

Non-working file

```
5093590,4808 N 15TH ST,Phoenix,AZ
```

Comment: I see address field here `5028156,2700 W BETHANY HOME RD,Phoenix,AZ,` Can you please specify how many columns does this data has?

Comment: There are a total of 5 columns but I only have data for 4.

Comment: please post a MCVE

Comment: I fixed the problem I added a csvwriter.writerow(row+[]) to the processing which gave me the trailing comma. The API is very particular about the csv files they accept.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are 5 columns defined in the csv example line here. `5028156,2700 W BETHANY HOME RD,Phoenix,AZ,`. The trailing comma means the last column of the CSV is null/blank.

In case of CSV files `1,,,,` translates to 5 columns where all the value in the columns are empty but first.

Removing the trailing comma will consider that row as having only 4 columns.

I hope that answers your question.